# Static Route MVC 4 only 1 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I have just one specific route to the controller and action.

I only have one controller and action and that is the only place I want to allow people to go:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Question", action = "Index" }
);
```

This is what I have at the moment, however, I don't want it to be allowed to go anywhere other than the `Question` controller and the `Index` action.

Answer (score 1):

The route in your question will enforce the rule you want. However I don't think you need "/" as the URL, I think an empty string "" will work just as well.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Question", action = "Index" }
);
```

Since you do not have any route parameter placeholders in your url, all requests for / will be routed to the Index action of the QuestionController. Furthermore, all other url's will return a 404 not found response.

Even though the 3rd argument to the method is "defaults", they will always apply. Since you did not specify a {controller} or {action} token in the url template, this route cannot be used to access any other actions on any other controllers.

Comment: What about `url: "*",`?

Comment: url: "" will not work either when entering any other URL than pure domain

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the possible URLs point to one single action you could do the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Question", action = "Index" }
);
```